# SQL Server 2012 Intellisense works, but for 2008 is does NOT work

Tags: sql-server-2008, intellisense, sql-server-2012, ssms-2012

From the day I got my machine before even opening SSMS 2008 they had installed on my machine, I had installed 2012, so I don't know if intellisense ever worked on 2008. However it is working on 2012. Did 2012 overwrite some dll or something in the registry?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  SSMS 2008+ should have intellisense when connecting to a 2008+ SQL Server.  If you do not get intellisense for a 2008 database I suggest you do a web search or contact Microsoft support.

Here's one [MS support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2531482) that illustrates a know cause regarding VS2010 SP1.